# PHPMyAdmin Fatal Error - Twig_Error_Loader

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Am using PHPMyAdmin 4.8.4, MySQL 5.7.24, PHP 7.3.0, and Apache 2.4.37.  Whenever I visit http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader: There are no registered paths for namespace "". in C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.8.4\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php on line 209
```

This error doesn't occur when using PHP 7.2.13.  I've examined the Filesystem.php and I do not see what is causing this problem with PHP 7.3.

Is their an easy way to remedy this error and have PHPMyAdmin work with PHP 7.3?

Comment: Unless you're trying to code a fix for this, it seems like the more appropriate action would be a bug report rather than a question here.

Answer (score 0):

probably the problem is this line in your php.ini :

**`zend_extension = "......php\ext\php_opcache.dll"`**

If enabled this original extension of php 7.3.0 phpmyadmin goes on throw exception...

Comment: What is the solution to be able to use PHPMyAdmin over https if the extension is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, try:

```
 brew uninstall php71 //if exists another version delete all
 enter brew uninstall --force php
 brew upgrade
 sudo brew services restart dnsmasq
 uninstall valet
 composer global update
 composer global require laravel/valet
 valet install
```

end install phpmyadmin if exists first uninstall:

```
brew install phpmyadmin
cd /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
valet link
```

Your phpmyadmin start : www.phpmyadmin.test ;)

Don't run ? try:

```
mysql -uroot
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root');
```

and enjoy, code, lives :)